# Inner scroll inside webview ,placed inside SwipeRefreshLayout is not working when scrolled up

Tags: android

The inner scrollup is not working in webview when the webview is placed inside the SwipeRefreshLayout. When the inner section is scrolled up it is taking the outer scroll in webview

### this is my layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
   <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    </WebView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### this is my main activity code

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.rgb(32, 135, 79));
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
                    if (webView.getScrollY() == 0 ) {
                        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                }
            });
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        webView.loadUrl("www.myurl.com");
```

Comment: share your code!

Comment: Please wait for 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
pullToRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.login_bg);
    pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
                if (webView.getScrollY() == 0 ) {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);

                    webView.loadUrl("www.myurl.com");
                }
                else
                {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                }
        }
    });
```

try this code..

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    String currentUrl = "https://news.ycombinator.com/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.login_bg);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

        webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
            }
        });


    }

    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            currentUrl = url;
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is pullToRefresh is the object of SwipeRefreshLayout??

Comment: webView.getScrollY() == 0 is checking the outer scroll in webview. But I am scrolling up the inner scroll in webview and it is refreshing the page. Please help me

Comment: i have also add some other code try that according that help full.

Comment: Can you please highlight the code that will be helpful